# What are the design differences between Pathfinder 2E and D&D 5E?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-2e, game-design, edition-comparison

(I do not believe this is a duplicate of [What are the major differences in style and system between D&D 5e and Pathfinder 2e? [duplicate]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165473/what-are-the-major-differences-in-style-and-system-between-dd-5e-and-pathfinder) -- despite the similar name, the answer there just mentions "rules vs rulings" but nothing else. I also do not believe it is a duplicate of [Does Pathfinder 2e have more in common with D&D 5e than it does with Pathfinder 1e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156621/does-pathfinder-2e-have-more-in-common-with-dd-5e-than-it-does-with-pathfinder), which is answered in a lot more technical detail.)

My question is: What are the very high-level design decisions (and, ideally, their effects) that differ between PF2E and D&D5E? I'm specifically *not* looking for "list of all mechanical differences", but only the overarching design decisions.

For reference, I have familiarity with all editions of D&D and PF1E but not PF2E.

Examples of the sorts of things I'm looking for:

- PF2E's compendium of rules vs D&D5E's expectation of DM rulings
- PF2E's level bonus to rolls vs D&D5E's bounded accuracy (leading to maximizing vs minimizing level differences)
- PF2E's expected magic items per level vs D&D5E's lack of expectations and prices (leading to magic item bazaar vs whim of the DM)

(A PF1E example would be the design of monsters being templates that class levels were added to, rather than D&D5E's monsters being static designs, though I don't know if PF2E functions the same way.)

Comment: So I’ve closed this as a duplicate. The linked question was definitely *incorrectly* closed as a duplicate of questions about other systems. No idea why.

Comment: I’ve bountied the other question, hopefully that will attract the sort of answer you’re looking for.